# Webpack successfully compiled but does not show output in browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, jsx

The webpack in my project runs successfully but when I reach to the desired port, it shows me the directory files. You can look at the image for the same.

[image]

My webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8100
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react_router",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "vinay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
  }
}
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

app.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

const App = () => <h1>Hello World</h1>

export default App
```

output==>

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You dont have a `index.html` file for webpack-dev-server to display. Add a `index.html` file with link to your bundle.

Comment: I do have index.html file in the App directory. But how do I add it to the bundle?

Comment: You need to give `bundle` script url in `index.html`

Comment: Read the [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html), its pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

edited answer:
I was able to get it to work:

1) create the actual dist directory under the root folder
2) make your output in your webpack.config.js look like this:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/dist/'
},
```

it will  tell webpack from where to serve your application.

3) add the following script to your package.json

```
    "build": "webpack -p"
```

it will build the bundle.js file

also, you will need an index.html file in your dist directory that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">  
     <title>Application<title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="app"></div>
     <script src="bundle.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

then, you run your build script and after that you can run the webpack server and it should work

Comment: do you acutally have a dist directory? could you also post the build output?

Comment: no it does not make a dist folder either but it says webpack compiled successfully.

Comment: This is the way I have my output directory set up:

const buildDirectory = './public/js/';

webpackConfig = {
...
       output: {
        path: path.resolve(buildDirectory),
        filename: 'app.js'
    }
...
}

Comment: Can you please explain why you did this const buildDirectory = './public/js/';

Comment: its just so i can change my build directory on directly at the top of the config file and the use it in the actual config directory. it shouldn't really matter if you do it the way i do it or the way you do it.

Comment: You can have a look at my edited answer to see how it works with index.html and how to make webpack create the bundle